# Can one disable tap-to-click in X server configuration, without synclient?

Tags: xorg, touchpad, x-server, ratpoison, altlinux

I want to configure my system so that tap-to-click is disabled on the touchpad. (It's running a rather old version of ALTLinux distro with xorg-server-1.4.2-alt10.M41.1.)

The most popular [advice](https://askubuntu.com/a/166407/19753) I have found is to execute `synclient MaxTapTime=0` in the user's X session.

I could accept this solution, but the problem is that this doesn't work for all users with their different preferred X "environment".

The first user has logged in in the linux console, and run `startx`. X server for his session has occupied the 7th virtual linux console. He uses bare ratpoison.

The second user has logged in, run `startx`.  X server for his session has occupied the 8th virtual linux console. He uses WindowMaker.

`synclient MaxTapTime=0` has had an effect in the second user's X session, but has had no effect when executed in the first user's X session.

So, can this setting be done system-wide, for the X server, perhaps in `xorg.conf`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to do it is by adding a file called `10-synaptics.conf` in the directory `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` (create the directory if it does not exist). In this file you can put something like

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "MaxTapTime"             "0"
EndSection
```

if `MaxTapTime` is the option you want to set.

It seems that (to be correct) `TapButton1` is the option you want to set, to `0` (for disabling *one-finger* tap), as in our example [here](http://git.altlinux.org/gears/x/xorg-conf-synaptics.git?p=xorg-conf-synaptics.git;a=blob;f=synaptics.conf;h=18954914d6106ea65f23d6e921bf8c8ec456b26b;hb=HEAD#l9). Setting `MaxTapTime` is just an ugly workaround.

```
# Which mouse button is reported on a non-corner one-finger tap (set to 0 to disable)
    Option "TapButton1" "0"
# Which mouse button is reported on a non-corner two-finger tap (set to 0 to disable)
    Option "TapButton2" "0"
# Which mouse button is reported on a non-corner three-finger tap (set to 0 to disable)
    Option "TapButton3" "0"
```

Note that the name of the file is not important, and you could as well use `10-notouchpadtap.conf`. The number however is used to define the order in which the configuration files are used by the system.

Comment: That's a nice answer, but probably this works only with newer servers. My `xorg-server-1.4.2-alt10.M41.1` doesn't accept an `InputClass` section... And my `xorg.conf` doesn't have any `InputDevice` sections (with a comment "With libXiconfig we don't need configuration for ps and usb mice."). So, as for now, I'm in doubt how to correctly put the wanted option into my `xorg.conf`...

Comment: Asked a specific question for my old X server without InputClass: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125264/4319

Comment: After creating the directory and the settings file, no daemon restart was needed! thought someone else would like to know.

Comment: In a fresh installation of an ALTLinux system, there might be already the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-synaptics.conf` provided by [xorg-conf-synaptics-0.2-alt1](http://packages.altlinux.org/en/Sisyphus/srpms/xorg-conf-synaptics) package with some frequently used options. One could simply add his custom configuration into this file. (It is marked as a "configuration" file by RPM, so RPM will try to be careful with one's custom configuration on upgrades.)

Comment: I've included the example how to disable the tap in [xorg-conf-synaptics-0.3-alt1](http://packages.altlinux.org/en/Sisyphus/srpms/xorg-conf-synaptics) in ALTLinux (which I've been using and had in mind when asking the question). One will have to just read [the file](http://git.altlinux.org/people/imz/packages/?p=xorg-conf-synaptics.git;a=blob;f=synaptics.conf;h=051f035ca1627a5c9033bcbe1d90bf262521af58;hb=ca067ffd80889b93dd5f3c83e234ec7580d1b4b1#l9) and uncomment a line.