# Can one disable tap-to-click in X server configuration without "InputClass" sections?

Tags: xorg, touchpad, x-server, xinput, altlinux

I want to configure my system so that tap-to-click is disabled on the touchpad. (It's running a rather old version of ALTLinux distro with xorg-server-1.4.2-alt10.M41.1.)

I'm interested in a solution without running `synclient` in each X session.

Probably, my X server is too old so that it doesn't understand "InputClass" sections in `xorg.conf`, as [suggested in another answer by Vincent Nivoliers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70435/4319):

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "MaxTapTime"             "0"
EndSection
```

The I get an error; from Xorg.*.log:

```
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
Parse error on line 71 of section InputClass in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf
    "InputClass" is not a valid section name.
(EE) Problem parsing the config file
(EE) Error parsing the config file
```

Also, my `xorg.conf` doesn't have any explicit "InputDevice" sections (with a comment: "With libXiconfig we don't need configuration for ps and usb mice.").

How do I put the "MaxTapTime" option into my `xorg.conf` so that the configuration of my input devices (including the touchpad) is not broken? (If I write explicit "InputDevice" sections, I might break the correct configuration obtained automatically..)

Perhaps, the output of `xinput list` can be of some use. I do not want to make the question too specific by posting my `xinput list` and asking what to do in this specific case. Let it be just an example:

```
$ xinput list
"Virtual core keyboard" id=0    [XKeyboard]
    Num_keys is 248
    Min_keycode is 8
    Max_keycode is 255
"Virtual core pointer"  id=1    [XPointer]
    Num_buttons is 32
    Num_axes is 2
    Mode is Relative
    Motion_buffer is 256
    Axis 0 :
        Min_value is 0
        Max_value is -1
        Resolution is 0
    Axis 1 :
        Min_value is 0
        Max_value is -1
        Resolution is 0
"AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"  id=4    [XExtensionKeyboard]
    Type is KEYBOARD
    Num_keys is 248
    Min_keycode is 8
    Max_keycode is 255
"PS/2 Mouse"    id=3    [XExtensionPointer]
    Type is MOUSE
    Num_buttons is 32
    Num_axes is 2
    Mode is Relative
    Motion_buffer is 256
    Axis 0 :
        Min_value is -1
        Max_value is -1
        Resolution is 1
    Axis 1 :
        Min_value is -1
        Max_value is -1
        Resolution is 1
"AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint"  id=2    [XExtensionPointer]
    Type is TOUCHPAD
    Num_buttons is 12
    Num_axes is 2
    Mode is Relative
    Motion_buffer is 256
    Axis 0 :
        Min_value is 0
        Max_value is -1
        Resolution is 1
    Axis 1 :
        Min_value is 0
        Max_value is -1
        Resolution is 1
$
```

I expect the answer to give some general advice, not specific for this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides `InputClass` there also exists a section called `InputDevice` which takes nearly the exact same options as `InputClass`.  Of course you cannot use the `Match*` operators but have to give the device's path explicitly:

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "touchpad"
    Driver "synaptics"
    Option "Device" "/dev/input/event<X>"

    Option "MaxTapTime"             "0"
EndSection
```

You'll just have to replace `<X>` with the appropriate device number.

Comment: Thanks! So, I'll have to figure out somehow (perhaps, from some logs) which `/dev/input/event<X>` corresponds to the touchpad... As a comment on the whole thing, now I see that the old way of configuration with "InputDevice" is not quite convenient because the assigned device files for the same physical might have different names after reboots (and/or adding new physical devices).